# Updating UI from background thread

Tags: android, handler

I was just testing out some basic handler stuff and below is the code. Now my question is that when I try o update the UI from background thread its updating. why is that? In my opinion I was expecting an exception to occur.

```
private Handler mHandler = null;
private Handler mUIHandler = null;

public static final int BACKGROUND_OPERATION = 10;
public static final int MAIN_THREAD_OPERATION = 20;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HandlerThread backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("BACKGROUND_THREAD");
    backgroundThread.start();
    mHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper(), this);

    mUIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), this);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BACKGROUND_OPERATION);
//            mUIHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MAIN_THREAD_OPERATION);
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mHandler.getLooper().quit();
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
    switch (message.what) {
        case MAIN_THREAD_OPERATION:
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("Updating from UI Handler");
            findViewById(R.id.textview).invalidate();
            break;
        case BACKGROUND_OPERATION:
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("Updating from background Handler");
            findViewById(R.id.textview).invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

//        message.recycle();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: where are you updating the ui from a background thread ?

Comment: `handleMessage ` method is running on UI Thread which is not effect by what you are sending by calling `sendEmptyMessage ` from other Thread

Comment: the Handler is instantiated from the ui thread, with the same looper of the main thread. handleMessage runs on the ui thread.

Comment: @Blackbelt even if its a different looper?

Comment: I didn't noticed that you have two different handlers. My bad. Try with a `Toast` instead of a `TextView` and see what happens

Comment: Toast showing too. Same result.

Comment: I see. Well getLooper can return null. If it is happening `mHandler` is instantiated on the ui thread looper. Check the return value of `backgroundThread.getLooper()`. If it is null or if it is equal to `Looper.getMainLooper()`

Comment: @Blackbelt Both are different and is not null as well.

Comment: to understand this: inside `handleMessage` call `Log.d` with the value of `Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: @pskink this is what I am getting. 
D/TAG     (24628): Thread[BACKGROUND_THREAD,5,main]

Comment: ok then start your `Thread t` not in `onCreate` but on some external event like button click, or call `mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(BACKGROUND_OPERATION, 3000);` inside `run` method

Comment: did this too its displaying as well..

    public void buttonClicked (View view) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(BACKGROUND_OPERATION, 3000);
        });
        t.start();

    }

Comment: it shouldn't work, just tested that, post the minimal working example then

Comment: try [this](http://pastebin.com/60f7LH7k), notice the delay of 3000 ms, it crashes, but when changed to 30 it doesn't

Comment: @pskink Can you please explain why the delay causes different behavior?

Comment: i dont know the details of `ViewRootImpl` where the checks are made but the rule of the thumb is: **dont touch the UI in non UI thread**